# Allowing unencrypted connections for anonymous binds only possible in openLDAP?

Tags: haproxy, openldap

I'm using HAproxy with a backend of openLDAP servers. I'd like to do the checking of the availability of the backend machines using `ldap-check` instead of the generic `check-tcp` (which I'm currently using).

ldap-check binds anonymously with no encryption when performing the check. Looking at [the documentation of ldap-check](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/aloha/10-0/traffic-management/lb-layer7/health-checks/), I see no way of configuring the bind-user and the use of encryption.

So, assuming I can not do a proper check (TLS + binding as specific user), I'm looking for a workaround. I may be able to convince myself to allow anonymous binding, but allowing for unencrypted connections is not something I want to do.

So, is it possible to (somehow) allow unencrypted connections for anonymous binds only? I guess not, since how do you know it's non-anonymous before the binding process has begun?

I currently have `olcSecurity: tls=1`, and I think I would need something like `olcSecurity: tls=1 simple_bind=0`, but that would allow any simple bind to be unencrypted (Not something I want to allow).

Maybe I should/could do the check by sending specific packages using `ldap-check` like shown [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/haproxy-and-authentication)? What is the best tool for getting the binary data? Should I just do a session with `ldapsearch` and `tcpdump`?

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do the checking from HAproxy using the `tcp-check` options `send-binary`and `expect binary` without compromising the security of my `openLDAP` configuration.

In my situation, I expect an attempt to bind anonymously to return the error code 48 (Not allowed). For the bind request, I was able to confirm the data sent in [the example I linked to in my question](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/haproxy-and-authentication). However, I needed a different response (Not allowed. Error 48)

Using a `pcap` file captured with `tcpdump`, I looked at an attempt to bind anonymously with `ldapsearch` with `Wireshark`. Doing that, I was able to see the raw data returned by `openLDAP` telling the client that the anonymous bind is not allowed.

Here is the relevant configuration from the HAproxy backend:

```
option tcpka
option tcp-check
tcp-check connect port 389
tcp-check send-binary 300c0201 # LDAP bind request "<ROOT>" simple
tcp-check send-binary 01 # message ID
tcp-check send-binary 6007 # protocol Op
tcp-check send-binary 0201 # bind request
tcp-check send-binary 03 # LDAP v3
tcp-check send-binary 04008000 # name, simple authentication
tcp-check expect binary 302502010161200a013004000419616e6f6e796d6f75732062696e6420646973616c6c6f776564 # 48 not allowed
tcp-check send-binary 30050201034200 # unbind request
```

I don't think `tcp-check expect binary` can be put in to more than one line like you can with `tcp-check send-binary`